# Tensorflow Tensor out of CSV has no size?

Tags: tensorflow

I just can't get any dimensions (size, lenght) out of this damn tensor "datatens". here is the code and the error message:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tflearn
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
file = 'some.csv'
record_defaults = [tf.float64]*18
from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv
data , label = load_csv(file, target_column=0,has_header=True,
                    categorical_labels=True, n_classes=50)

datatens = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data,label))
print(datatens.get_shape().as_list())
```

ERROR:

```
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((17,), (50,)), types: (tf.string, tf.float64)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "basic_class.m", line 44, in <module>
print(datatens.get_shape().as_list())
AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

FOLLOWUP:

after getting eager execution running im curious, why my tensor is integer instead of float. here is the output of the advised code.

CODE:

```
print(tf.shape(data))
print(tf.shape(label))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("Shape_1:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`, you get a [dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), not a tensor. A dataset is essentially a container of tensors, and you can access its tensors in a few ways.

The simplest way is to call the dataset's [make_one_shot_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#make_one_shot_iterator) method. This returns an iterator that cycles through the tensors. The best documentation on datasets and iterators is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets).

Are you sure you want to call `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`? Aren't `data` and `label` already tensors?

EDIT:

If you want to validate the tensor containing labels, try this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tflearn
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv

tf.enable_eager_execution()
file = 'some.csv'
record_defaults = [tf.float64]*18
data, label = load_csv(file, target_column=0,has_header=True,
                    categorical_labels=True, n_classes=50)
print(tf.shape(label))
```

Enabling eager execution is important because it lets you access the tensor without having to create and run a session.

Comment: I try to validate the imported data - having a look on e.g. labels. first of all I would like to know the dimensions (check1) after that I would like to print out the first row to have a more detailed look on it.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I am getting this annoying [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18304) but could manage it. anyway turning on eager execution brings this output. `Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)` what is my size now?

Comment: The output implies that the tensor's _shape_ contains two integers. To see the actual values of `data` and `label`, call `print(data)` and `print(label)`.

Comment: okay, now I tried the the print command and it shows all the data of "data" but "labels" seem to be empty. it looks like this `[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]` there are integers between 0 and 50 in the first column of the csv. this should be the label. what's missing?

Comment: Spaces or strange punctuation in the CSV file? Are you mixing up `label` and `labels`? If you'll provide a couple lines of CSV data, I'll try to replicate your error.

Comment: here is a line: `6,1,43,25,13,11,24,9,27,0.005730656792771283,148435864.0582435,0.00001395554607401769,361477.5085666379,8.2,300,2.6,2000,1010.8` PS: i am calling always "label"

Comment: Your code and data look fine. It looks like your issue closely resembles [this one](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/pull/950).

Comment: okay, I had some more intense view on my data and labels seem to be fine now... just was confused - sorry. My problem is now only how to normalize each column on its own (cause the min-max is very different in every column) I have found that so far, but it is normalizing generally. ` data = normalize(data, axis=0, norm='max') `